# How to decompress .bin file that has no header or magic bytes?

Tags: linux, compression

So i have a compressed data , but couldn't know the compression methode , The decompressed size written in header of the main file whitch contains this compressed data , Its not .7z or .lzma or any common type , Any suggestions may help. thanks!
This is the first part of data

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

Comment: The first two bytes of the file are "7Z", while the actual 7-zip archive bytes start with "7z" (with a lower case "z"). Perhaps this file was created by an ancient version of the program? Or some other program that was pretending to be "compatible" with 7zip? Where did this file come from? What is is meant to be?

Comment: Thanks for your answer , This is just first part from entire data in software of  ''Digital satellite receiver'' , This block contains OSD strings like "No signal , install , no program found, and more things, in the last few monthes this data was compressed with .lzma but after  firmware update it looks like that ! Not .7z i tried it many times , I believe its compressed because the size written in firmware header.

Comment: If it is from some kind of satellite receiver then chances are it is compressed and the important data is encrypted. They may well have taken the open source 7zip compressor and modified it to suit their own needs and security requirements such as adding an extra layer of obfuscation in which case decoding it is non-trivial as there is likely some part of the puzzle you do not have. You would likely need the code for whatever loads this "archive".

Comment: I Hope some one talk about this encrypted archive. Thanks alot for your help